# Authentication issue with CUPS 5.3.1 on SMB Printer

Tags: 12.04, printing, smb

I am trying to print to a samba printer via CUPS. I have configured the printer allright, but there seems to be a problem with authentication. The error message I get is

```
Session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

The GUI also tells me: `Idle - Tree connect failed (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)`

It used to work with previous versions of CUPS (1.4.3 and 1.4.6) under Ubuntu 11.04

I am doing this on a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04, CUPS version 1.5.3. I have tried changing some rights relating to apparmor, with no success as described here: http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2010/01/16/fixing-usrlibcupsbackendsmb-failed-error-in-ubuntu/

I have been working with Ubuntu for years - but this is the kind of problem I need help with.

Comment: I also tried downgrading to CUPS 4.1.8, that did not help, I could not connect to localhost:631 any more. I am now back at the issue described above, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hurrah, its working.
The problem is related to a really strange authentication issue that 12.04 has with `samba`. As I also had  problems connecting to the `samba` drives, I [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134249/connecting-to-windows-7-shares-from-12-04) that server and domain names need to be in uppercase (I have no clue why) to make them work.

For the `samba` printer, it was enough to just have the domain name uppercase, such as this:

```
smb://D.EXAMPLE.CH/vpp-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/vpp-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

take care to unlock caps lock before entering the password :-)

I hope this saves someone time.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the "really strange authentication issue"?

Comment: In my case the domain name points to a netbios print server and as: 1) netbios names are (almost) always uppercase and 2) we (in UNIX/Linux) assume case sensitively then it should be in UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Go to Terminal and run:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```
2. There change:

   ```
   workgroup = YOURDOMAIN
   ```
3. Test syntax is ok by typing in terminal:

   ```
   testparm
   ```
4. On system settings -> printer -> properties, set the authentication details as follows:

   ```
   Username youruser@domain.com
   Password yourpass
   VERIFY
   ```
5. Print test page

That should do it

Comment: This seems to do the trick also on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: For Fedora29 I did not see "authentication details"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although on a debian machine where the Windows host is connected to the domain but the Debian client is not.
The solution that worked for me was as follows:

1. Change the domain setting as suggested by [Miguel](https://askubuntu.com/a/812707) above.
2. Test for access to the printer using [this command:](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-and-Windows-Shared-Printing/printing_to_windows.html)

   > /usr/bin/smbclient -L {Server_IP} -U {ad.domain.name.com}/{domain_username}
3. Fire up the add printers dialog in Gnome, select Windows Printer via Samba