# Transfer data from Windows Vista via Ethernet to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, samba

This is my first time using Ubuntu. I want to transfer my files (pictures, Music, Documents) from Windows Vista to Ubuntu via Ethernet. I understand that I have to configure  the IP but how do you that? Also, I read somewhere that I have to use Samba? but not sure if I have to install it in Windows or both? And how?  I would really appreciate your help.

-Engels

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134249/connecting-to-windows-7-shares-from-12-04

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both computers are connected to the same network. On your Windows machine open command line (cmd) and type ipconfig /all. Check your IP address.
On your Ubuntu machine click the network icon on top right corner and click connection information. Make sure that the only difference in the IP addresses is the last number of the four (meaning they're on the same network)

Once you confirmed that they are on the same network, on your windows machine, share the folder with everyone. There are various ways to do this. In Explorer, right-click the folder select sharing and add "everyone" to the list of those how can read this folder. BTW, you may also enable writing but it is a security risk.

Once you've done this, on your Ubuntu computer open Nautilus, Browse the network, find your Windows computer and copy your files.