# How to open shared SMB resources in the form "\\host"?

Tags: networking, samba

I want to download data from my university local server, whose IP is like 10.1.2.3.

From Windows I could open *Run...*, type `\\10.1.2.3`, and the local server window opens.

How is it possible to perform this task in Ubuntu?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide#Ubuntu_Clients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu's default file manager is called `nautilus`, however it is simply labelled "Files" in most versions.

### Using Nautilus

As Vsevolod already mentioned, you can open the files application in order to connect. To do this click the 'connect to server' button in the left sidebar and enter in the information.

You might need to know what type of server it is (chances are it is a normal windows share`samba`), so you could try typing in "smb://10.1.2.3".

### Using the Unity Dash

Another way which I cannot guarantee will work, but you might want to try, is to press ALT+F2. This is the pretty much the equivalent of the Windows "Run..." prompt. Here you can type commands and the system will execute them.
Try typing "smb://10.1.2.3" here and click on the result (should be named "10.1.2.3").

Comment: Upvoted. Any idea how to do it with the windows machine's name? like `//ELZIN`?

Answer (score 8):

Open your File manager. Open Dash and write `files` or just press the folder Icon in the right launcher.

press CTRL + L on your keyboard or just press on Go -> Location from menu bar.

[image]

In the field on the top menu write : smb://IP-To-Connect

[image]

then press enter

---

**Another GUI method**

Open your home as above then go to `File->connect to server` from the menu bar.

[image]

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 and below

Then choose `Windows Share` From Type then complete the needed infor like username and password ...

[image]

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and beyond then just enter  `smb://IP-To-Connect` in the server Address field
and press enter

[image: Connect to server]

**Easy Way to Open the connect-to-server**

Open terminal

```
ctrl + Alt + T
```

type:

```
nautilus-connect-server
```

[image: Connect to server]

Then complete steps as above

Answer (score 1):

Open file manger (Nautilus, for example), after press file -- connect to server and write ip.

Comment: how can i know which file manager i have? M new in ubuntu

Comment: click on the file/folder icon in the launcher (on the left side of your desktop)